# How to get the file from the folder based on date in java

Tags: java

I have multiple files in a folder with a naming convention

```
Name_MoreName_DDMMYYYY_SomeNumber_HHMMSS.txt
```

How can I get the file which has oldest date and time (i.e. oldest DDMMYYYY and HHMMSS).

For in the following example:

```
Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072334.txt
Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072134.txt
Name_MoreName_24012012_SomeNumber_072339.txt
Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072135.txt
```

... the oldest file will be

```
Name_MoreName_22012012_SomeNumber_072134.txt
```

Comment: get the file names, sort them and pick top/bottom as per sorting

Comment: i want to get the last added file in the folder and my file name if-logFile_2016_Jun_02_115011....

Comment: I have edited my answer to assist with the change in file name pattern. Feel free to upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First, read the file names into a `List<String>`.

Then sort the list using a comparator that understands the format of the file name:

```
public class FileNameComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*?_([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})_.*?_([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\\.txt$");
    private static int[] groupOrder = new int[]{3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6};

    @Override
    public int compare(String filename1, String filename2) {
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher(filename1);
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(filename2);

        return compareMatchers(matcher1, matcher2);
    }

    private int compareMatchers(Matcher matcher1, Matcher matcher2) {
        if (matcher1.matches()) {
            if (matcher2.matches()) {

                // for each group in the correct order (year, month, date, hour, minute, second)
                for (int group : groupOrder) {
                    int result = compareValues(matcher1.group(group), matcher2.group(group));
                    if (result != 0) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }

                return 0;

            } else {
                // filename 2 is incorrect pattern
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            // filename 1 is incorrect pattern
            return 1;
        }
    }

    private int compareValues(String value1, String value2) {
        return new Integer(value1).compareTo(new Integer(value2));
    }
}
```

To sort:

```
List<String> filenames = ...; /* populate the list of filenames */
Collections.sort(filenames, new FileNameComparator());
```

To get the oldest, take the first one. To get the youngest, take the last one.

**Edit**: if your updated file name pattern is:

```
if-logFile_2016_Jun_02_115011.txt
```

... then the regular expression and code will need to change to be able to extract the parameters and perform the correct comparison. The regex would be:

```
^.*?_([0-9]{4})_(.{3})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\\.txt$
```

... and you would process them in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and when you process the second group, you need to compare in month name order.

Comment: Edited to cover change in filename pattern.

Comment: File f1 = new File(DownloadFromFilecabinetACH + System.getProperty("file.separator")+nsFile.getName());
                                   f1.delete(); plz tell me what is wrong is that

Comment: Is this a new question? If so, please post as a separate question.